# Assigning sections of a matrix to lists based on row value

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I'm working with a very large (4x41355) matrix and I'm trying to make lists out of sections of rows based on the value in the fourth row. It's like this:

```
{{p1, p2, p3,...,p41355},{x1, x2, x3,...,x41355},{y1,y2,y3,...,y41355},{1,1,1,...,613}}
```

I'm looking for a way to make lists for x and y based on the fourth row. So all x values that have a 1 in the fourth row are assigned to a list (for a total of 613 lists), and then do the same for y values (for another 613 lists).

I really have no idea how to approach this, answers much appreciated.

Edit: I'll try to give an example with a smaller matrix.

```
{{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6},{y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6},{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2}}
```

What I would want from this would be:

```
xlist1={x1, x2, x3, x4} 
xlist2={x5, x6}

ylist1={y1, y2, y3, y4}
ylist2={y5, 56}
```

Comment: Can you give a small example where you give a small version of the list with the expected output? It's a little unclear what you mean, actually, by row, why there are 613 lists, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2}};

tra = Transpose[{#, Last@list}] & /@ Most@list;

{xlist1, ylist1, xlist2, ylist2} =
  (Cases[#, {a_, 1} -> a] & /@ tra)~Join~(Cases[#, {a_, 2} -> a] & /@ tra)
```

> {{x1, x2, x3, x4}, {y1, y2, y3, y4}, {x5, x6}, {y5, y6}}

Answer (score 1):

```
l = {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2}}
Transpose[Most /@ Transpose /@ GatherBy[Transpose@l, Last]]

(*{{{x1, x2, x3, x4}, {x5, x6}}, {{y1, y2, y3, y4}, {y5, y6}}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which makes use of a tail-recursive function. It is somewhat more complex than any of the other answers because it handles cases where the data is ragged.

```
splitter[{}, _, new_] := List @@ Flatten @ new;
splitter[_, {}, new_] := List @@ Flatten @ new;
splitter[old : {__}, runs : {__}, new_: tmp[]] :=
  Module[{car, cdr},
    {car, cdr} = TakeDrop[old, UpTo[First[runs]]];
    splitter[cdr, Rest[runs], tmp[new, car]]]
```

`splitter` applied to the example given in the question

```
example = {{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2}};
{vals, {tags}} = TakeDrop[example, 2];
With[{runs = Length /@ Split[tags]}, splitter[#, runs] & /@ vals]
```

> `{{{x1, x2, x3, x4}, {x5, x6}}, {{y1, y2, y3, y4}, {y5, y6}}}`

Now I generate data that is complex enough to show `splitter`'s behavior with ragged data.

```
SeedRandom[1];
runList = Flatten @ Table[ConstantArray[i, RandomInteger[{1, 5}]], {i, 5}]
data = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 99}, Length@runList], {2}]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5}
> {{97, 9, 49, 64, 41, 29, 67, 93, 32, 9, 77, 90, 34, 1, 77, 76}, 
>  {43, 57, 97, 20, 39, 4, 22, 80, 58, 30, 41, 88, 6, 73, 68, 41}}
> ```

With arrays of the same length:

```
With[{runs = Length /@ Split[runList]}, splitter[#, runs] & /@ data]
```

> ```
> {{{97, 9, 49, 64, 41}, {29, 67, 93}, {32, 9, 77, 90, 34}, {1}, {77, 76}}, 
>  {{43, 57, 97, 20, 39}, {4, 22, 80}, {58, 30, 41, 88, 6}, {73}, {68, 41}}}
> ```

With five elements clipped off the end of each row of `data`:

```
With[{runs = Length /@ Split[runList]}, splitter[#, runs] & /@ data[[All, ;; -6]]]
```

> ```
> {{{97, 9, 49, 64, 41}, {29, 67, 93}, {32, 9, 77}}, 
>  {{43, 57, 97, 20, 39}, {4, 22, 80}, {58, 30, 41}}}
> ```

With two elements clipped off the end of `runList`:

```
With[{runs = (Length /@ Split[runList])[[;; -3]]}, splitter[#, runs] & /@ data]
```

> ```
> {{{97, 9, 49, 64, 41}, {29, 67, 93}, {32, 9, 77, 90, 34}}, 
>  {{43, 57, 97, 20, 39}, {4, 22, 80}, {58, 30, 41, 88, 6}}}
> ```